# My query is not returning results

Tags: sql

I am so very new at SQL and a little frustrated. I am sure my query is written wrong since it will not return any results. I need to determine how many people between the ages of 14-19 have had a physical at a particular school(s) within  the last two years. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT      PatientProfile.Last, 
            PatientProfile.First, 
            PatientProfile.City,     
            PatientProfile.Birthdate, 
            PatientProfile.SchoolName, 
            Appointments.ApptStart, 
            ORDERCODES.CODE, 
            DoctorFacility.PlaceOfServiceMId
FROM        PatientProfile 
INNER JOIN  ORDERS          ON  PatientProfile.PId = ORDERS.PID 
INNER JOIN  ORDERCODES      ON  ORDERS.ORDCODEID = ORDERCODES.ORDCODEID         
INNER JOIN  DoctorFacility  ON  PatientProfile.DoctorId = DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId 
                                AND PatientProfile.FacilityId = DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId 
                                AND PatientProfile.PrimaryCareDoctorId = DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId 
                                AND PatientProfile.RefDoctorId = DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId 
INNER JOIN  Appointments    ON  DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId = Appointments.DoctorId 
                                AND DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId = Appointments.FacilityId 
                                AND DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId = Appointments.ResourceId
WHERE   (PatientProfile.Birthdate BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2001-09-01 00:00:00', 102) AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '2005-09-01 00:00:00', 102)) 
AND     (Appointments.ApptStart > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-09-01 00:00:00', 102)) 
OR      (PatientProfile.City = 'Salem') 
OR      (PatientProfile.City = 'Peabody')
ORDER BY PatientProfile.Last, PatientProfile.City
```

My query runs without error but I do not get any results. Maybe one of the joins is wrong. I would appreciate any help offered.

Comment: If any of those joined tables do not have any results you will not return anything. I would comment all the joins and add them back one at a time to find the table that unexpectedly doesn't have the results you expect it to.

Comment: Provide a http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: You may want to start debugging your query by simplifying conditions in `WHERE` clause (leave them out one by one) and perhaps narrowing `JOIN` to less tables.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your table structure, so I can't give you a solution to your problem, but this jumped out to me as being completely wrong:

```
INNER JOIN  DoctorFacility  ON  PatientProfile.DoctorId = DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId 
                                AND PatientProfile.FacilityId = DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId 
                                AND PatientProfile.PrimaryCareDoctorId = DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId 
                                AND PatientProfile.RefDoctorId = DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId     
INNER JOIN  Appointments    ON  DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId = Appointments.DoctorId 
                                AND DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId = Appointments.FacilityId 
                                AND DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId = Appointments.ResourceId
```

You are using `DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityId` for *each* of these comparisons.  You should be using the appropriate column to `JOIN` on.  This is most certainly why you aren't getting any results.

Comment: I know this is wrong. My data needs to display the following: PatientProfile.last, PatientProfile.First, PatientProfile.Birthdate (as age between 14-19). DoctorFacility.Orgname, Orders.Code, and Apptslot.Apptstart. I do realize the above example shows Appointments but realized I need to pull from a different table (Apptslot). I can do very basic queries but this requires four tables and is much more complicated than what I am skilled at currently.

Comment: My Table structures are: PatientProfile.DoctorID=DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityID, PatientProfile.FacilityID=DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityID, PatientProfile.RefDoctorID=DoctorFacility.DoctorFacilityID, PatientProfile.PrimaryCareDoctorID=DoctorFacility.FacilityID, PatientProfileID=OrdersID, DoctorFacilityCity.DoctorFacilityID=ApptSlot.FacilityID